# Lubuntu 12.10 PPC-Can't Login after install

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, login, yaboot

I installed Lubuntu 12.10 PPC alt. Install on my ibook g4, yaboot failed to install so I used the advice given in the PPC FAQ, ["I've lost yaboot what can I do](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#I.27ve_lost_yaboot.2C_what_can_I_do.3F), and I was able to boot to a black screen with and move the arrow but that's all, when trying to login by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> I kept getting "invalid" login. I reinstalled and yaboot failed again, except this time I am unable to boot even to a black screen and trying to login via pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> still gives me an invalid login message despite the fact I know 100% I am correctly typing in my username and password.

EDIT: For some reason, another reinstall went smoothly despite using the disc. I was able to login but had to use single user mode to reset my password as the invalid login error occurred again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what question you are asking so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to answer!  The black screen is described on the known issues page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCKnownIssues#A12.10_Quantal_Quetzal

Are you installing to an external hard drive?  Yaboot shouldn't fail to install on 12.10 because I submitted a patch, but you won't have an automatic boot into a usb/firewire drive.  If yaboot really hasn't installed then something horribly has gone wrong, and this may possibly explain your failed login.